# What is the grease or lubricant at the end of my new rotary hammer drill tool?

Tags: drill, lubrication

Recently purchased a rotary hammer drill and some kind of grease or lubricate was at the bit end (opening) of my tool. I'm wondering what kind of grease is this?

I was watching a few videos and someone in the comment section claimed that not that many people know about the grease the needs to be applied often. I glanced over the manual to find out what the substance was and didn't see anything right away, so I figured I'd ask the question here.

[image]

What is this substance?

How often is someone supposed to apply this inside bit area or the dust shield?

Does it depend on tool brand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t say exactly what the grease is, but manufacturers sell it as a specific item. (For example, [https://www.amazon.com/Makita-194683-7-Grease-Vessel-Bit/dp/B005GNCGG2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005GNCGG2) )

The theory is that you use it every time. (And wipe your bits approximately clean after you use them.) The reality is probably more like, “Uh, I haven’t lubed in a while… maybe I should…”

Typical application is to dip the drill end of the bit into the tube of grease to get a little bit on before you insert the bit into the drill. Too much and it'll stay on the outside where it'll collect dust, which isn't useful.

It doesn’t depend on tool brand. There’s moving parts in every rotary hammer chuck that need lube.

Comment: Googling "SDS grease" will find lots of it, many makes. You want the right stuff because it's 'rubber safe' so wont rot your seal. Seems to be molybdenum disulphide.